# Adding values from lines to columns (transport costs)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following problem (see picture below).

I have a table with transport costs between villages.
Source is the village from where transport starts & target is the village  where transports ends.

The costs of transport from village 1 to 2 is not the same as from village 2 to 1.

Now I do have the reverse cost figures, but in another line (see picture).

Now I want to add the transport costs from village 2 to 1 into the column `reverse costs`.

As I have about 7000 relations it's not possible to make it manually. Please suggest how to do via a SQL query.

[image: Transport costs]

Comment: **Edit** your question and add the complete table definition (as `create table` statements), some sample data (as **formatted** text) and the expected output based on that sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update query over a self join like below

```
update t
set revcost= t2.cost 
from t t1 left join t t2
on t1.src=t2.tgt and t1.tgt=t2.src
where t.src=t1.src and t.tgt=t1.tgt;

select * from t order by id;
```

**See working SQL fiddle here**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ecd54/12

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think this will do what you seek:

```
update village v1
set
  reverse_cost = v2.cost
from
  village v2
where
  v1.source = v2.target and
  v2.source = v1.target and
 (v1.reverse_cost is null or v1.reverse_cost != v2.cost)
```